# É possível alterar a função do botão físico, mesmo com o app em background?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de alterar a função de um botão físico, por exemplo o volume, ao clicar no botão, baixo ou cima, seja possível realizar alguma função, diferente da alteração do volume do aparelho? Isso é possível? Se sim, há algum exemplo?

Ps.: Com a *activity* na tela eu fiz o que desejava, gostaria de saber se é possível e como fazer mesmo com o *app* em *background*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece não ser possível, no entanto para alguns determinados casos como o Google Play Music (serviço de *stream* de musica), ele usa o `KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN` e `KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` para diminuir e aumentar o volume da música que estar a tocar, independente se o *app* está aberto ou não. Entretanto, querendo ou não, não foge da questão do volume, que por si, é em relação a musica. Você pode pesquisar um pouco sobre o [`VolumeProviderCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat.html) adicionado ao SDK pelo Google a partir da API 22.  Talvez uma limitação seja a versão do Android. Mas pode ter certeza, talvez você tenha um caminho longo a percorrer para chegar até lá.

Veja essas perguntas:

- [Is it possible to create an Android Service that listens for hardware key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986337/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-service-that-listens-for-hardware-key-presse)
- [onKeyDown in a service? (Global Hot Keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454710/onkeydown-in-a-service-global-hot-keys)

Comment: Vou pesquisar, muito obrigado!